# Simplest examples of unique-solution and unsolvable-without-backtracking Sudoku-like problems 

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, recreational-mathematics

A

The Sudoku game admits a broad generalization as follows : let $r$ be an integer $\geq 2$
and let $X$ be a finite set, and ${\cal X}$ be a collection of $r$-subsets of $X$ 
(i.e, a $r$-uniform hypergraph on $X$). We call any mapping $X \to \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,r\rbrace$ a coloring of $X$.

Then, the Sudoku-like problem associated to any partial colouring $g$ of $X$ (i.e. $g$ is
a mapping from a subset of $X$ to $\lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,r$) is to extend $g$ to a colouring $f$
such that $f$ restricts to a bijection onto $\lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,r\rbrace$ 
(a "rainbow coloring") on each $X\in {\cal X}$. To avoid trivialties, we always assume
that $X$ is not fully  colored from the start, i.e. that $g$ is not defined on the whole of $X$.

We say that a Sudoku-like problem is perfect if it admits a unique solution, and reducible
if there is a non-backtracking rule that allows one to deduce the  color
of an initially uncolored vertex $x\in X$ (formally this means
that $g$ is not defined at $x$ and that  there is a color $c\in \lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,r$ such that either (1) for any color $c' \neq c$ there is a $Y\in {\cal X}$ containing $x$ such that $c'\in g(Y)$ or (2) for any vertex $x' \neq x$ there is a $Y\in {\cal X}$ containing $x'$ such that $c\in g(Y)$).

Perfect irreducible Sudoku-like problems do exist (the ordinary Sudoku problem in the end of David Eppstein's arXiv paper http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0507053v1 is one such). It is natural then to look for "simpler" perfect irreducible  Sudoku-like problems,
i.e. with the smallest possible value for $r$, and with as few hypergarph edges as possible.  It is easy to see that we must have $r>2$. Are there examples with $r=3$ ?

Comment: Did you check with David's answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27361/do-actual-sudoku-puzzles-have-a-unique-rational-solution/27480#27480 ?

Comment: 
  @Wadim : Yes, of course. AFAIK, all the sudoku-like problems studied are ordinary sudoku problems or more complicated variants : in my notation, the value of $r$ is $9$ or higher. I, on the contrary, am looking for simpler examples, say $r=3$.

Comment: @Ewan, thank you for clarification.

Comment: Fano plane?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.01.04

Comment: Except there is no nice 3-coloring.  Perhaps some sub-configuration of the Fano plane?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.01.04

Comment: @ Gerhard : I think it should be remembered that if there is no initial coloring the solution to the sudoku-like problem is clearly nonunique (as colors may be permuted), so that the initial coloring is an important matter.

Comment: Yes.  However, configurations which lend to unique solutions once an admissible partial coloring is given have an appeal; cf my post.  In other news, I suspect that projective planes are over configured and will not lead to any rainbow colorings.  Minimal "Sudoku spoilers", those which cannot be rainbow colored and have few hyperedges, may also be of interest to you.  Gerhard "If You Don't Succeed, Publish" Paseman, 2011.01.04

Comment: Also, are bipartite graphs too reducible for you?  A few words explaining why r > 2 would be appreciated.  Gerhard "Run That By Me Again?" Paseman, 2011.01.04

Comment: @ Gerhard : if r=2, our hypergraph is just an ordinary graph and our coloring becomes an ordinary vertex coloring, with just two colors, 1 and 2. Then if x and y are two adjacent vertices, we have f(y)=3-f(x), and likewise we may determine the color of any vertex in the connected component of $x$.
   Thus, if the Sudoku-like problem is irreducible, every connected component is either completely colored or not colored at all (in which case there are exactly two admissible colorings on it). 

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time interpreting "simple" in this context.  "Simple" might be a fully colored object (so there is no work to do), or an object with few r-subsets present.  Let me suggest a related but possibly alternative route.

Given an underlying set X and a collection of r-subsets of X all of which are to be rainbow colored, we call a subset U of X universal iff [for any (unique) allowed coloring of X, there is a unique induced coloring on U and vice versa] .  U is a minimal universal set if no proper subset stirctly contained in U is universal.  Simple here is again ambiguous:  X may be a simple universal set, or X - {x} for any singleton set {x}.  Or it may be those U which are minimal universal.  I prefer to look at the latter out of mathematical interest.

Some unverified results of mine are minimal universal sets of size 5 for the 4-color, 16-square sudoku, and 48 for the popular 81-square version.  It strikes me that projective planes and certain other combinatorial designs are also good candidates for the study of your generalized Sudoku problems.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.01.04

Comment:  @Gerhard : I agree my use of the word "simple" was unfortunate. I'll edit the OP accordingly
 

Comment: Finite Geometries are "Sudoku spoilers": they have too many sets to rainbow color.  Short proof sketch: color a point.  If a line is supposed to be rainbow colored, then no other point on that line gets the same color.  But every two distinct points determine a line.  So one needs as many colors as points.  Gerhard "It's Amazing How Thinking Helps" Paseman, 2011.01.04